# Using jQuery Mobile with Smarty Templates

Tags: php, mobile, jquery-mobile, smarty

I am considering using both jQuery Mobile framework and also Smarty Templates in a single object-oriented PHP project.

I believe that javascript issues between the two can be resolved (see other questions about jQUery standard and Smarty), but what about things like form elements?

Smarty has its own way of templating select and other form elements, and so does jQuery mobile.

I see that there is no Smarty plugin for jQuery Mobile, so is it actually possible to use these two technologies together without extensive workarounds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, they will work perfectly fine together. Smarty does not force you to use any of it's functions. You can use Smarty to write plain HTML Markup and insert values from PHP as Variables. Smarty even gives you the opportunity to write your own functions, so you can integrate jQuery into Smarty on your own.